# Mapbox/Leaflet marker flicker when pinch zooming

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

Using this code

```
const layerOptions = {
      sanitizer: () => null,
      pointToLayer: ({ properties: { type, status } }, pos) => {
        if (type === "city") {
          type = "city"
        }
        let iconUrl = `img/pin-${type}`
        if (status) {
          iconUrl += `-${status}`
        }
        iconUrl += ".png"
        const icon = L.icon({
          iconUrl,
          iconSize: [48,48],
          iconAnchor: [24, 48],
        })
        return L.marker(pos, { icon })
      },
    }
    this.itemLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer(items, layerOptions).addTo(this.map)
```

and a `zoomend` listener on the map the marker icons flicker like they are changing z-order constantly when the map is pinch-zoomed. That only happens on mobile devices (Android), not on the desktop.

Any ideas what might cause this?

Comment: Please specify your leaflet/mapbox.js version.

Comment: Mabox: 2.4.0 which comes with Leaflet: 0.7.7